# Как сохранить массив в справочнике 1С?

Tags: 1с

У меня есть справочник пользователей. Также есть процедура, которая высчитывает профили доступа, которые есть у пользователя. Я хочу записать эти профили пользователю в виде массива в реквизит, но в настройках реквизита нет типа массива. Как это можно сделать?

Понимаю, что можно в виде строки с разделителями, но это кажется не совсем правильным вариантом.

Comment: можно в ХЗ выгрузить.

Comment: А для чего нужно хранить в пользователе данные о его профилях? Может вообще вы не с того края к задаче подходите?

Comment: @Sagittarius мне нужно сделать отчет таблицу, в котором в первой строке будут имена пользователей базы, в первой колонке - профили доступа, а внутри таблицы будут строки "Да", "Нет" (в зависимости от того, есть ли у данного пользователя профиль)

Comment: А зачем хранить данные о профилях в пользователе? Они же как-то и так связаны с пользователями.

Comment: Мне кажется вы не по той тропинке решения идёте.

Comment: Согласен с предыдущими комментариями. Попробуйте сделать отчет БЕЗ использования СКД; В цикле формируйте выходную форму отчета, с помощью Таб.ПрисоединитьСекцию("Юзер|Профиль");